# Is the solution of this ODE analytic with infinite radius of convergence?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= f(x)\\
x(0) &= x_0 
\end{align}

where $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$, and $f:\, \mathbb{C}^N \mapsto \mathbb{C}^N$ is analytic in $x$. In fact $f$ is a polynomial.

Now, by other means, I can show that the solution $x(t)$ is bounded for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$: $\Vert x(t) \Vert = 1\,\, \forall t \in\mathbb{R}$.

I believe that this (together with form of $f$) implies that the solution can be extended to the whole real line. This because $x(t)$ cannot blow up or leave the domain of $f$. Is this correct?

I can also show that the solution is analytic on the whole real line (i.e., that the Taylor series of the solution at each $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$, converges in a neighborhood of $t_0$)

The main question is: does this implies that the Taylor series of the solution at $t=0$ has infinite radius of convergence? If not what else is missing to prove this last assertion?

Comment: Analytic means that you have a Taylor series in every point that converges in a non-trivial neighborhood to the function. Not that there is one point where the Taylor series has an infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes absolutely. I corrected the question

Comment: Then you need that the solution is an entire function in each component. This is highly unlikely for non-linear $f$. In general the radius of convergence is the distance in the complex plane to the closest singularity. The location of the singular points in the complex plane is however not determined only by $f$, they are specific to every solution/initial condition. There will also be special solutions like the constant ones at equilibria that trivially have an infinite radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this counter-example.

The logistic equation $ \dot x= 2x (1-x)$

[Edit: $ \dot x= x (1-x)$

has one solution given by  $x= \frac{1}{1+ e^t}$   whose initial condition is $x(0)=1/2$

This solution can be obtained by elementary methods involving separation of variables and partial fraction decomposition.

Note that $x(t)$ is bounded for all real values of $t$.

If the solution $x(t)=\sum_j c_j t^k$ could be expanded as a power series in $t$ that has an infinite radius of convergence,  then  it would have a complex extension $f(z)= \sum_j c_j z^k=\frac{1}{1+ e^z}$ that would be an entire function. But $f(z)$ has singularities at $z=(2k+1)i\pi$.

**Theorem.** *The non-constant solutions of the scalar ODE  $\frac{dx}{dt}= P(x)$ cannot be entire  when the right-hand side is any polynomial of degree two or more.*

Proof. If  $\frac{dx}{dt}= P(x)$ is a polynomial in $x$, then in factored form  $$P(x)= a \Pi_k (x-\alpha_k)^{m_k}$$

Choose any solution $x(t)$  whose initial data $x(0)$ avoids all such roots $\alpha_k$.
Suppose that $x(t)$ can be extended as  entire function of the complex variable $t$.  Picard's Little Theorem [Picard Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) asserts that an entire function $x(t)$ can omit at most one value from its range.
Thus the solution $x(t)$ must pass through  one of the roots $\alpha_k$ at some  $t_0$.

But then $x(t)\equiv \alpha_k$ must be locally constant near $t=t_0$ by the local existence and uniqueness theory of ODE's. And since $x(t)$ is entire, that implies $x(t)$ is globally constant.

P.S. The same proof applies when $P(x)$ is any entire function of $x$ that has at least two zeroes. Thus for example $ \frac{dx}{dt} = \sinh x$ has no nontrivial entire solutions, because the complex function $\sinh (z)= -i \sin(iz)$ has many complex zeroes, located  at $z=k\pi i$.

P.P.S. A little web-searching indicates that the question for nonlinear systems is quite murky. You could try asking your question on MathOverfow and see if any expert has fresh info.
[polynomial systems](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21619/entire-solutions-of-polynomial-odes/21653#21653)

And I bring to your attention the classical Jacobi elliptic functions which satisfy a beautifully symmetrical quadratic system of equations. (Jacobi Elliptic Functions from a Dynamical Systems Point of View
by Meyer, Kenneth R.
The American mathematical monthly, 10/2001, Volume 108, Issue 8)
The solutions are doubly-periodic functions in the complex plane that have poles on a lattice. (They are not entire)
[Jacobi functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions)

Comment: Are u sure $2$ comes in $2x(1-x)$ ? Interesting Answer man.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Interesting counter example. I'll think about it a bit. In any case what do you think would be needed in order to show the last assertion?

Comment: @Balaji sb Oops.  The 2 was a mistake which I will edit out.  Thanks for correction.

Comment: Very nice extension. Unfortunately I'm interested in the non scalar case. Do you think your theorem could be extended to that case?